# How to enable the right click menu in the text box on my Google Chrome extension popup?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I am creating a text box where the user will enter some input in my Google chrome extension popup.

```
<div align="center">
<input type="text" id="textbox" size="25" style="height:30px;font-size:14pt;"/>
<br>
<script>document.getElementById('textbox').focus()</script>
</div>
```

But, to my surprise, when I right click inside the displayed textbox, no menu shows up!

How can I enable the context menu?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context menus are disabled in popups. You can star [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37850).